# how to get the filename and filebody?

Tags: javascript, css

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        $('#uploadme').click();
    });

    $('#uploadme').change(function(){
        $('#filename').val($(this).val());
    });
});

<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Browse" />
  <input type="text" id="filename" />
  <input type="file"  id="uploadme" />

<style>

    #uploadme {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  visibility: hidden; 
}
</style>
```

From these , I need to get the file name and filebody which I select(For Eg: filename.txt) .. Please provide a solutionenter code here

Comment: Have you read the documentation for FIle API. If you want to upload files through JS. [FILE API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) and [Filereader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) . There is a step by step documentation for [reading files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: Note that if your code relies on FileReader (and does not have a fallback approach) it will not work on IE9 - http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader.